# Moodle Student list with Groups and Course

Tags: moodle

I am using moodle2.4.6. I want a list of user with their groups and their courses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to do an SQL query to get this information.

Assuming you are using the default 'mdl_' prefix for tables, you will need to join together the following tables:

- mdl_user - the details of the users
- mdl_user_enrolments - (user_enrolments.userid = user.id) which course enrolments the user
  has
- mdl_enrol - (enrol.id = user_enrolments.enrolid) details of which
  enrolment instances these are
- mdl_course - (course.id = enrol.courseid) details of the courses these users are enroled in
- mdl_groups_members - (groups_members.userid = user.id) details of the
  groups these users are in
- mdl_groups - (groups.id =
  groups_members.groupid AND groups.courseid = course.id) name and
  description of the groups the user is in (for each course)

Please comment if you need help turning that pseudo code into actual SQL, or if you need help with the Moodle database access API ( http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API )

Comment: i write the query but this is not execulting

Comment: If you have debugging on for your Moodle site, then you should get an error message and that will give you a clue as to what is going wrong. The above may have some typos in it, but it is basically the right method to use to find the details you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT
  mdl_user.username,
  mdl_user.firstname,
  mdl_user.lastname,
  mdl_course.fullname,
  mdl_course.idnumber,
  mdl_groups_members.groupid,
  mdl_groups.name
FROM (mdl_groups_members
  INNER JOIN ((mdl_course
    INNER JOIN (mdl_user_enrolments
      INNER JOIN mdl_enrol ON mdl_user_enrolments.enrolid = mdl_enrol.id)
      ON mdl_course.id = mdl_enrol.courseid) INNER JOIN mdl_user ON mdl_user_enrolments.userid = mdl_user.id)
    ON mdl_groups_members.userid = mdl_user.id) INNER JOIN mdl_groups
    ON (mdl_groups.courseid = mdl_course.id) AND (mdl_groups_members.groupid = mdl_groups.id)
WHERE (((mdl_user.username) = "102993") AND ((mdl_course.category) = "36"))
```