# How can get the list of courses an student belongs to in moodle 1.9?

Tags: moodle

I already checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158121/moodle-student-list-with-groups-and-course) but some of the tables posted I dont have in my db (I'm 
also using the same prefix 'mdl_')

I was wondering if anyone knows of a query that can print the courses a specific student is enrolled in.  I tried this query which doesn't output any errors, it just doesn't display the correct info: ($userid is declared before the statement)

```
SELECT c.fullname
FROM mdl_course c
LEFT OUTER JOIN mdl_context cx ON c.id = cx.instanceid
LEFT OUTER JOIN mdl_role_assignments ra ON cx.id = ra.contextid
AND ra.roleid =  '5'
LEFT OUTER JOIN mdl_user u ON ra.userid = u.id AND u.id = $userid
WHERE cx.contextlevel =  '50'
```

If anyone has an idea please let me know...Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a Moodle 1.9 query.

For Moodle 2, you need something like this:

```
SELECT c.fullname
FROM mdl_course c
JOIN mdl_enrol e ON e.courseid = c.id
JOIN mdl_user_enrolment ue ON ue.enrol = e.id 
WHERE ue.userid = [userid]
```

A fuller query would also check for status = 0 for the enrol and user_enrolment records (and also check the start / end dates, but that should be enough for the basic cases.

(Apologies for any typos - I don't have the code in front of me to test this)

Comment: I'm sorry for not specifying but yea it moodle 1.9...thanks for your answer